# why the result of my date object always several hours behind the actual string that I want to convert?

Tags: ios, swift, date, datetime

I am a junior iOS developer. and now I have problem when converting string to date object.

I don't know why the result (date object) always 7 hour behind the actual string I input. currently I am in Indonesia (GMT + 7), I don't know, but maybe it is related to the place where I live. here is the code I use

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
    let x = dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-07-18 12:00:00")
    print(x)


result: 2018-07-18 05:00:00 +0000
```

how to fix this? really need your help

Comment: 12-5 = 7 (your time zone )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working very well. There is nothing wrong with it. The value printed is 100% correct.

`Date` objects do *not* store anything about time zones and when printed, it will always be in the GMT (UTC+0) time zone. This is why `+0000` appears at the end of the printed string. `Date` objects represent **a point in time**. 12:00 in Indonesia is the *same point in time* as 05:00 in GMT.

So whenever you want to see the `Date` object as a string in *your* time zone, you need to use a `DateTimeFormatter` like you did here and set the `timeZone` of the formatter.