# String to date with UTC timezone

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I am struggling with `Date` and I'm assuming is `TimeZone`.
Currently I get from my backend a string like this `"2020-04-07"` and when I try to convert it to date it turns into `2020-04-06 22:00:00 +0000`. I am in Spain (UTC+2) which I guess this is why it removes 2 hours?

This is my date formatter:

```
var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        return dateFormatter
    }()
```

And I call it `dateFormatter.date(from: startDateString)`

I am setting my current timezone but seems to be ignoring it or am I missing something?

I have followed a lot of answers from here but it's always the same result.

Thank you

Comment: How are you outputting the description of the Date object? If you're just printing it to the console it will show it in UTC by default.

Comment: @shim what?? Really?? I just do a normal print()! How can I see what I'm sending to the server then?

Comment: The `Date` object does not have any inherent locale / time zone. It just represents a moment in time. If you want to see that `Date` as a string you have to use a date formatter. Or there's `descriptionWithLocale`. I don't know how you're sending it to your server.

Comment: if I am understanding correctly and if you want ur date unchanged from whats returned from backend, then you can use `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)` to keep the date unchanged.

Comment: I see no problem here. 2020-04-06 22:00:00 +0000 is 2020-04-07 00:00:00 in Spain, right? Note that Spain is two hours ahead of UTC, and dates are always `print`ed in UTC.

Comment: I feel like this question is the one that has been asked hundreds of times before. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397856/why-the-result-of-my-date-object-always-several-hours-behind-the-actual-string-t/51397957#51397957), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49023814/swift-convert-string-to-date-output-wrong-date/49023964#49023964) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688517/ios-swift-date-without-time/55688630#55688630). Can you explain how your question is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Date` object does not have any inherent locale / time zone. It just represents a moment in time. If you want to see that `Date` as a string in a specific locale/time zone you have to use a date formatter. Or there's `descriptionWithLocale`. If you use `print` it will print a debug description of the `Date` instance in UTC.